# How to call actions right after each other in react-redux

Tags: react-redux

I have a problem that I cannot figure out how to tackle that with react-redux

I have an app which constantly produce some logs (from beacon device) and store them in state (consider 2 logs/second). 
Then I need to send this logs sequentially (in same order) to server api and remove them from the state.

Since calling api is async, I cannot call them in a loop, because I need the first api call be done and call for the next row then (the second call needs some information from the first call)

Right now I have the logs ready-to-send in store, but I cannot figure out how to process them.

Comment: Why do you want to keep logs in the store, as opposed to something like an array? They are not used for rendering the UI, are they?

Comment: I have any array in store, is there any other way to persist them?

Comment: Since they don’t affect the logic of your app, I would keep them separately. Sending them is a matter of firing up an API request, and if it succeeds, removing all the logs that have already been sent. I’m not quite sure which part of this causes a problem but maybe if you post some code, I can help.

Comment: @DanAbramov in future it's needed to show the logs in a separate page, and even dumping all of the store to disk and restoring it when applications is open, so right now not persisting them in store is not an option

Comment: "because I need the first api call be done and call for the next row then (the second call needs some information from the first call)" is vague and it’s hard to write code without understanding what you mean exactly. Do you want to send logs by one line, each line in a single API call? Wouldn’t that be very slow?